# Use bluetooth microphone in Google Assistant

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, google-assistant, headset

I'm trying to set up my motorcycle Bluetooth headset (Fodsports BT-S2) to let me use Google Assistant. It has the following Bluetooth profiles:

- A2DP-SNK
- AVRCP
- HSP
- HFP

I've managed to find an old APK of 'Smart Bluetooth Headset' which has allowed me to map the normal 'redial last number' button to the more useful 'Google Assistant'. That seems to be working flawlessly, opening the assistant and making the normal beep awaiting voice input.

The problem I have is that it doesn't pick up the audio from the microphone on the headset, only from the phone itself. I've tried various combinations of the settings within the Google Assistant, as well as various mono routing apps to try and get it to work. One of these mono routing apps was successful at one point. However, my setup was no longer using A2DP, and so I was forced to endure poor sound quality.

Is there any way I could either:

1. Make Google Assistant correctly use the microphone on my headset?
2. Force the phone to use only the microphone part of my headset, instead of the phone's built-in microphone, whilst retaining the A2DP mode for audio?

Comment: IS the device locked at the time? Scrolling through the Google app within Menu --> Settings --> Voice there should be a section for Hands-free.

Comment: @BoLawson I believe so, could that make a difference? The phone would be in my pocket, and I haven't set it up with Smartlock. I have enabled 'Bluetooth Audio Recording', 'Allow bluetooth requests with device locked' and 'allow wired headset requests with device locked'.

Comment: Yes it could, also within the Google app Menu --> Settings --> Google assistant --> assistant at the bottom there is also a Assistant devices section is the bluetooth device added there if not try adding it and also if you click on the bluetooth device there are more options specific to that device.

Comment: @BoLawson No luck unfortunately, checked in there and it just shows 'Phone' which gives me the same settings as previously. I can only add new IoT devices in there. So far nothing I try is allowing it to pick up my voice from the BT microphone, only the one from the phone itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with [Google Voice Access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.accessibility.voiceaccess). I came across [these instructions](https://profandroid.com/network/bluetooth/bluetooth-headset-voice-commands.html), which seem to be for [Google Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googleassistant). Executing them did not seem to affect the desired change in Voice Access, but I think they might work for you with Assistant.

The configuration is performed in the main [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) app. After opening it, I clicked "⋯ More", then "⚙ Settings", then " Voice", and there - under the "Hands-Free" heading, I found an option for "Bluetooth audio recording", subtitled "Enable audio recording through Bluetooth devices if available. See [the linked instructions](https://profandroid.com/network/bluetooth/bluetooth-headset-voice-commands.html) for screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make this work in a way that, although satisfactory to my needs, is an absolutely convoluted hack.

1. Found a version of the 'smart Bluetooth headset' apk from before the functionality to remap the redial button was stripped out.
2. Unfortunate this old version didn't support Tasker correctly (just did nothing when trying to select a tasker task). As such, I had to install the new 'smart Bluetooth assistant' and open this when redial was chosen. This was then set to open a module once loaded, which was a task set up in Tasker.
3. The task was set up to open BTmono (full version), call the BT_ON intent of BTmono, activating the hfp on my headset and allowing the microphone to work. It then waited 2 seconds before starting a 'voice search', opening the Google assistant which now hears me. Fortunately my headset cancels the BTmono connection just by pushing the hangup button, allowing the headset to return to A2DP once I had finished my command.

Convoluted, messy and takes 4 apps to get the job done, but works surprisingly reliably so far.

Would be grateful if anyone has any better suggestions, but for now this will do!

Comment: Hi Jonno. I also have been trying to figure out a way to get Ok Google or even Hi Bixby working through my Samsung Buds while driving my motorcycle. Is this still working for you? Have you found a better solution yet? Do you have to press a button on your phone to initiate this? Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your Bluetooth device goes into power saving mode, and need to be woke with a button press, a more advance model device may listen for the Google wake up commands while power saving mode, or a setting on the master device.

https://support.google.com/headphones/answer/9027902?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en
https://support.google.com/headphones/answer/7520404?hl=en&ref_topic=7518050
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en
https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7283669?hl=en&ref_topic=7172845
https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/7394009?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en